# How do I combined these code? (Read more, Read Less with Scroll To Top)

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I have a few paragraphs displayed on the header of my page. I don't want all the text to show so I have a read more and read less button. Currently when the read less button is clicked the page remains in the middle. I'd like for when the read less button is clicked for it to also scroll back to top. I found these two codes and both give me my desired function separately. I would like to combine the code but I am unsure how as I am still learning JavaScript.

Here's the coding (Thanks In Advance):

```js
  function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

```css
#more{
 display: none;
}
#myBtn{
 border:1px solid #000 /*none*/;
 background:none;
 font-family:caviardreams;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:0 10px 0 10px;
 margin:-5px 0 0 5px;
 letter-spacing:5px;
}.first{
    width:100%;
}
.second {
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="second" id="second">
<p>sum dolor sit amet, ex pri utamur volumus, usu graece platonem an. Possit labitur assueverit et pro. Eum in erant dictas mnesarchum, sed veritus perfecto menandri et, graece omittam mea cu. Exerci facilisis intellegat has ea, cu sea explicari assentior appellantur, tale offendit pertinax ut vel. Id viris consectetuer sed. Mea ea wisi suscipit voluptaria.</p>
<span id="dots"><button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button></span>

<span id="more"><span id="less">
<p>sum dolor sit amet, ex pri utamur volumus, usu graece platonem an. Possit labitur assueverit et pro. Eum in erant dictas mnesarchum, sed veritus perfecto menandri et, graece omittam mea cu. Exerci facilisis intellegat has ea, cu sea explicari assentior appellantur, tale offendit pertinax ut vel. Id viris consectetuer sed. Mea ea wisi suscipit voluptaria.</p>

<p>sum dolor sit amet, ex pri utamur volumus, usu graece platonem an. Possit labitur assueverit et pro. Eum in erant dictas mnesarchum, sed veritus perfecto menandri et, graece omittam mea cu. Exerci facilisis intellegat has ea, cu sea explicari assentior appellantur, tale offendit pertinax ut vel. Id viris consectetuer sed. Mea ea wisi suscipit voluptaria.</p>

<p>sum dolor sit amet, ex pri utamur volumus, usu graece platonem an. Possit labitur assueverit et pro. Eum in erant dictas mnesarchum, sed veritus perfecto menandri et, graece omittam mea cu. Exerci facilisis intellegat has ea, cu sea explicari assentior appellantur, tale offendit pertinax ut vel. Id viris consectetuer sed. Mea ea wisi suscipit voluptaria.</p>

<div class="first"><button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))">Click Me!</button></div>

<span id="dots"><button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read Less</button></span>
</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function which scrolls back to the top is executed when you click the button here:

```
<div class="first"><button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))">Click Me!</button></div>
```

The `onclick` part triggers the `smothScroll()` function in the JavaScript code.

Now the Read Less part is executed in `myFunction()` in the if condition. If you add the `smoothScroll()` at the bottom of the if condition it should work as you want:

```
if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second')); // <-- here
}
```

Now that you know how you can achieve what you want, I would suggest that you clean up the code a little bit and try to understand how everything works. You could also google about modern JavaScript etc. This would be a good exercise to improve your JavaScript knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('about'));
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);
    
    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);
    
    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

```css
.about{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:599;
    width:65%;
    float:right;
    margin:55px 40px 70px 0;
    display:block;
}
#more{
    display:none;
}
#myBtn{
    outline:0; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#fff;
    color:#4f9190;
    font-family: bonvenocf-light;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display:block;
    margin:-10px auto 0;
    padding:0 5px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about" id="about">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut velit nunc, semper ac nunc quis, interdum suscipit nisi. Fusce sagittis vitae lorem vel porta. Sed eget elit commodo, lacinia dui vulputate, accumsan tellus. Nullam lorem est, consectetur id ultrices vitae, aliquam ac purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas rutrum, enim ut luctus volutpat, tortor ex efficitur felis, vitae fringilla nunc mauris ac nisi. Etiam ut blandit leo, vitae dignissim mi. Suspendisse vestibulum felis hendrerit, eleifend dui vitae, suscipit nunc. Phasellus finibus velit ac purus rutrum maximus. Etiam ut eleifend ligula, eget tincidunt lacus.</p>
<span id="dots"></span>

<span id="more">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut velit nunc, semper ac nunc quis, interdum suscipit nisi. Fusce sagittis vitae lorem vel porta. Sed eget elit commodo, lacinia dui vulputate, accumsan tellus. Nullam lorem est, consectetur id ultrices vitae, aliquam ac purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas rutrum, enim ut luctus volutpat, tortor ex efficitur felis, vitae fringilla nunc mauris ac nisi. Etiam ut blandit leo, vitae dignissim mi. Suspendisse vestibulum felis hendrerit, eleifend dui vitae, suscipit nunc. Phasellus finibus velit ac purus rutrum maximus. Etiam ut eleifend ligula, eget tincidunt lacus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut velit nunc, semper ac nunc quis, interdum suscipit nisi. Fusce sagittis vitae lorem vel porta. Sed eget elit commodo, lacinia dui vulputate, accumsan tellus. Nullam lorem est, consectetur id ultrices vitae, aliquam ac purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas rutrum, enim ut luctus volutpat, tortor ex efficitur felis, vitae fringilla nunc mauris ac nisi. Etiam ut blandit leo, vitae dignissim mi. Suspendisse vestibulum felis hendrerit, eleifend dui vitae, suscipit nunc. Phasellus finibus velit ac purus rutrum maximus. Etiam ut eleifend ligula, eget tincidunt lacus.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read More</button>
</div>
```